# Method reference in attribute before method is defined causing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

I don't understand why this works;

```
class parentClass(object):
    pass

class childClass(parentClass):

    def my_meth(var):
        print(var)

    a = {'meth': my_meth}

x = childClass.a['meth']("Helloworld")
```

Whilst this fails;

```
class parentClass(object):
    pass

class childClass(parentClass):

    a = {'meth': my_meth}

    def my_meth(var):
        print(var)

x = childClass.a['meth']("Helloworld")
```

It would *seem* that a class is read line by line on execution and if the method definition has not been parsed before it is referenced within an attribute, an error occurs?

Is this true? Why does this occur in class/static attributes whilst you can def methods in any order and reference them from other methods written above or below them?

Is there a way to keep the class attributes at the top of the class to preserve readability and consistent layout?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are calling the function before defining it though you can define functions in any order.

Comment: "Why does this occur in class/static attributes whilst you can def methods in any order and reference them from other methods written above or below them?" because the body of functions arent executed when they are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would seem that a class is read line by line on execution and if the method definition has not been parsed before it is referenced within an attribute, an error occurs?

Yes, that is true. Class definitions are executed from top to bottom, just like module-level code. You can even put things like if/else statements and for loops directly inside the class body.

> Is there a way to keep the class attributes at the top of the class to preserve readability and consistent layout?

Your first example is fine. The order is not considered strange in Python.

That said, you do have potential alternatives. You could, for example, create a `@classmethod` to initialize class attributes at the top of the class, and then call immediately after the class declaration, e.g.

```
class childClass(parentClass):

    @classmethod
    def _initialize(cls)
        cls.a = {'meth': cls.my_meth}

    def my_meth(var):
        print(var)

childClass._initialize()
```

You could even write a class decorator to do this step for you (if you think that's prettier), as they execute after the class declaration code has completed execution.

> Why does this occur in class/static attributes whilst you can def methods in any order and reference them from other methods written above or below them?

Executing a function *definition* is different from calling the function *object* it creates. The former just creates the function object and assigns its name to the local context. The latter runs its code.

Classes are just fancy dicts. You can swap attributes in and out of them at runtime. When you do a `self.foo()` inside of a method `bar`, the `.` operator is doing an attribute lookup of the `foo` attribute on the `self` object. It's a similar idea when using `cls.foo()` in a classmethod.

It's entirely possible to write a function that references an attribute that doesn't exist. It will fail with an `AttributeError`, of course, if you call it, but if somehow the attribute gets set later, then you can call it successfully.